# Laravel appending extra data along with custom response in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am calling a function which is in my laravel controller. I have used laravel's custom response to return data. But some other data is getting added to my response even though I have not added it.

```
return Response::make(json_encode(array(
    'error' => false, 
    'message' => 'Redaction done successfully.', 
    'is_redacted' => 0)), 200, 
    array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    )
);
```

Above is the code that I have added to return my response.
But response that I am receiving is:

```
    > * Found bundle for host redaction-stage-tcm.tylerhost.net: 0x55998c67ee40
    * Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host redaction-stage-tcm.tylerhost.net
    * Connected to redaction-stage-tcm.tylerhost.net (208.64.239.110) port 443 (#0)
    > POST /ocr/OCRWeb/v2/Documents('mfr_8')/OCRWeb.Scan HTTP/1.1
    Host: redaction-stage-tcm.tylerhost.net
    User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4
    OData-Version: 4.01
    OData-MaxVersion: 4.01
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 2
    upload completely sent off: 2 out of 2 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200 
    < Cache-Control: no-transform
    < Cache-Control: no-cache
    < Cache-Control: no-store
    < Cache-Control: must-revalidate
    < Cache-Control: max-age=0
    < Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    < Vary: *
    < Pragma: no-cache
    < X-Clacks-Overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
    < OData-Version: 4.01
    < Preference-Applied: 
    < Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
    < Content-Length: 163
    < Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2019 10:44:40 GMT
    < 
    * Connection #0 to host redaction-stage-tcm.tylerhost.net left intact
    {"error":false,"message":"Redaction done successfully.","is_redacted":0}
```

I have called some rest APIs in my function. This data is related to that but why is it getting appended to my custom response??
Please help me with it.

Comment: Then what exactly are you trying to return? And I am not sure, just a guess, the `Response` facade that you have used must be of some other namespace and not of Laravel (`Illuminate\Http\Response`).

Comment: Am I missing something? The content seems fine. If you are bothered by the default headers, note that you are **attaching** custom headers with your code not replacing the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
return response()->json([
   'error' => false, 
   'message' => 'Redaction done successfully.', 
   'is_redacted' => 0, 
   'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
], 200)
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. Even if I send null object still it's appending that data :(

Answer (score 0):

create a Middleware called `AddToRequest` and registered it in Kernel.php. See the code below

**AddToRequest.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;

class AddToRequest {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->request->add(['dummy' => 'hey man', 'date' => Carbon::now()]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'inject' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AddToRequest'
    ];

}
```

In the `handle()` method of the `AddToRequest` Middleware, I set two variables and add it to the request

```
$request->request->add(['dummy' => 'hey man', 'date' => Carbon::now()]);
```

Then, in my controller I use the `inject` middleware

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('inject');
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

In the `index()` method of the controller I inject the use `Illuminate\Http\Request` object and pull the variables I set in the middleware from the request object as follows:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->get('dummy'), $request->get('date'));

    return view('welcome');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your case was similar to mine, I was trying to log an object from a function called in my API controller using print_r in Laravel's log. I used print_r without the "true" switch and as a result instead of returning it as a string, it was sending it to stdout and thus prepending it to the normal response of the controller.
Changing the log command to:

```
Log::info(print_r($myObject, true));
```

solved the issue for me.

[print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) (without the *true* parameter), [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) (without the *true* parameter), essentially are trying to "print on the screen" whatever variable(s) you have provided as parameters, and since API calls do not return their response directly to the screen, these functions' output is prepended to the response the API would normally return. Removing them, or using them with the true parameter (for print_r and var_export) which returns their output as string, instead of sending it to stdout, will allow the API to just return its expected response.